# MultipleChoiceField form not displaying user's instance of form

Tags: django, django-views

I've implemented a MultipleChoiceField form with a CheckboxSelectMultiple. It works perfectly in that the form is displayed and user selected options are saved to the BaseServicesOffered model as desired. The problem is that when the user goes back to the form, the checkboxes that the user had previously selected/submitted are not selected -- they are all unchecked. I'd imagine that it's a problem with my views.py. Here is my code:

models.py

```
class BaseServicesOffered(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)    
    service = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

forms.py

```
class BaseServicesOfferedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    service = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user')  #this takes in the value of 'user', which is passed from the view function.
        super(BaseServicesOfferedForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['service'].choices = [(t.id, t.service) for t in AllServices.objects.filter(industrycode=user.userprofile.industry)]

    class Meta:  
        exclude = ('user',)
        model = BaseServicesOffered
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="/accounts/login/")    
def baseservicesoffered(request):

    try:
        base_services_offered = BaseServicesOffered.objects.create(user=request.user)

    except:
        pass    

    user = request.user
    instance = get_object_or_404(BaseServicesOffered, user=user)
    form = BaseServicesOfferedForm(request.POST or None, user=request.user, instance=instance)    

    if request.method == 'POST':

        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            service = form.cleaned_data['service']
            services = [int(i) for i in service]  
            instance.service = services
            instance.save()
            return redirect('/accounts/profile/')

        else:
            context = {'form': form}
            return render(request, 'accounts/setup8.html', context)

    context = {'form': form}            
    return render(request, 'accounts/setup8.html', context)
```

setup8.html

```
   <form id="post_form" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        {{ form.non_field_errors }}

        {% csrf_token %}

        {{ form.as_p }}

        <div class="submitbutton">

            <button type="submit">
                SUBMIT
            </button>

        </div>

    </form>
```

Update:

This is how you store a list of ints in the Charfield:

```
    service = form.cleaned_data['service']
    services = [int(i) for i in service]  #converts list of strings to list of ints
    instance.service = services
```

I've updated my code above with this.

Comment: A `models.CharField` isn't designed to store multiple choices. If you look at the value stored in the database it will be something like `"['choice1', 'choice2']"` (that's a string, not a list). You might find a library like [django-multiselectfield](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield) useful.

Comment: thanks. is there no model field in django that will store lists by default?

Comment: If there was I would have mentioned it ;)

Comment: LOL. Fair enough :)

Comment: I've figured out how to store a list in a CharField. Please see update on initial post.

Comment: I would have thought that would store a string like `"[1, 2]"`. Parsing that might be tricky. You might find it easier to store a comma separated string, e.g. `"1,2"`.

Comment: I wasn’t quite correct to say Django doesn’t have a field that stores lists. If you are using Postgres, there is [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).

Answer (score 0):

```
multiple_choice = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    label=u"Select multiple", 
    choices=MY_CHOICES, 
    widget=forms.widgets.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
    initial=(c[0] for c in MY_CHOICES)
)
```

You should set the `inital` parameter for the options to be checked for a particular user.

Comment: I dont really want a default value set. I just want the options that the user checked on a previous form submission to appear when they load the form again.

Comment: I now see how this will help me potentially. Thanks!